# Ошибка переноса проекта

Tags: java, android

Перенёс проект из репозитория на компьютер. После переноса всплывает ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде как все должно решаться просто, но не выходит.
Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.0'

    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Текст ошибки:

> ERROR: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.    build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK
>   Build-Tools 28.0.3    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28 To
>   build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the
>   missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation
>   to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
> Using Android SDK: C:\Users\jone1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk Install
>   missing SDK package(s)

Comment: А ошибка то какая? То что что на скрине нам ни о чём - это предупреждение, что гредл не синхронизирован. А причина должна быть указана во вкладке Build.

Comment: Скиньте скрин ошибки. То, что вы указали не есть ошибка. Ну и попробуйте в студии сделать: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: @woesss, добавил текст ошибки

Comment: Странно - вы же вроде не из командной строки собираете проект... В любом случае у вас не хватает перечисленных пакетов - откройте SDK-manager и установите, заодно и лицензии примите, из-за которых гредл не может скачать их сам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tools"->"SDK Manager".
На вкладке "SDK Tools" поставьте галочку "Show Package Details".
Убедитесь, что в разделе "Android SDK Build-Tools", рядом с версией 28.0.3 стоит галочка.
Если отметите ее, он предложит скачать после нажатия на "ОК". Необходимо будет принять лицензию.